# How can I remove /index from my homepage of Craft CMS?

Tags: craft3

How can I remove /index from my homepage of Craft CMS?

https://pritirathod.com/index

Comment: As in, you don't want https://pritirathod.com/index to load, just https://pritirathod.com? Have you tried setting up a .htaccess redirect?

Comment: Yup .htaccess redirect is perfect. This only occus when I go https://pritirathod.com/ and then I go on any other page and then click back the homepage.